# How to show the file upload name for jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

How to show the file upload name for jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin v1.48?

After the users have uploaded the file, is there a way to show the file that they have uploaded under the profile?

```
1.if ( isset($_FILES['tb-documents']) ) {        
  $documents = $_FILES['tb-documents'];
  foreach ( $documents['name'] as $key => $value ) {
   if ( $documents['name'][$key]) {
    $document = array(
     'name' => $documents['name'][$key],
     'type' => $documents['type'][$key],
     'tmp_name' => $documents['tmp_name'][$key],
     'error' => $documents['error'][$key],
     'size' => $documents['size'][$key]       
     );
        $status = wp_handle_upload($document, array('test_form' => false));

    if( !isset($status['error']) ) {
     $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
     add_user_meta($user->ID, 'tb-documents', $uploads['url'].'/'.basename($status['file']));
    }                 
   }

  }
 }
```

The upload is working well on the user profile. However, I want to pull out the file name that they have uploaded and display all the uploaded file names to them.

Which variable should I use?

```
1.I tried this, $content .= '.$documents['name']'; but it doesn't work. It shows syntax error.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine results from this `$documents['name'][$key]` and show it to user.
For example:

```
if (isset($_FILES['tb-documents'])) {
    $uploadedFiles = array();
    $documents = $_FILES['tb-documents'];
    foreach ($documents['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($documents['name'][$key]) {
            $document = array(
                    'name' => $documents['name'][$key],
                    'type' => $documents['type'][$key],
                    'tmp_name' => $documents['tmp_name'][$key],
                    'error' => $documents['error'][$key],
                    'size' => $documents['size'][$key]
            );
            $status = wp_handle_upload($document, array('test_form' => false));

            if (!isset($status['error'])) {
                $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
                add_user_meta($user->ID, 'tb-documents', $uploads['url'] . '/' . basename($status['file']));
                $uploadedFiles[] = $documents['name'][$key];
            }
        }   
    }

    var_dump(implode(", ", $uploadedFiles));
}
```

Comment: Hi, which variable should I use to pull the file name?  $content .= '<br><a href="' . $documents[$y] . '#">Download Document #' . ($y+1) . '</a>';
            } This is the code I am using, but it shows the text link as download document. Is there a way to change the fixed download document # to text which shows the actual filenames?

Comment: Can't you use $documents['name'][$key] ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the uploaded files to the uploader, you can handle it easily in JQuery using the `fileuploaddone` callback provided by jQuery uploader

```
$('#fileupload')
    .bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
            console.log( data['result']['files'][0]['name'] );
            console.log( data['result']['files'][0]['url'] );
        });
```

If you have multiple files, you need to loop over `data['result']['files']` array.